# Calculating the solubility of aspirin in water

Tags: solubility, titration, medicinal-chemistry

I am trying to investigate the relationship between the solubility of aspirin in water with the relationship to some variables. In my investigation, I seem to be stuck with the calculation of finding the solubility. Since reacting aspirin with aqueous NaOH affects solubility, one possible direction I considered taking is investigating the effects on the solubility by changing the amount of aspirin input. Or maybe keeping the aspirin input constant but change the amount of NaOH in the reaction. Either way, the calculation for the solubility is required, but how does one numerically calculate the solubility upon reacting with NaOH?

One way I found online, is dissolving aspirin into a conical flask. Titrate it with x amount of NaOH and record the final and initial volume of neutralization. Using the data, I would try and find the amount of dissolved aspirin in the flask, and basically, compare the amount with the amount stated for the tablet. But how will this give rise to the actual finding of the solubility? It will allow me to get the dissolved amounts, but is that the quantity of solubility? I heard solubility is grams/liter.